# I'm using gwt and I can't capture international characters using a keypress event listener

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, character, keyboard-events

onkeypress doesn't seem to capture characters such as vowels with accents eg "á". 
My application has a listener for keypress events. I run it on development mode and I'm using chrome and firefox on a mac computer. Googling the problem didn't offer me any information.

I thought I'd also mention it should have nothing to do with encoding the source files as UTF-8. It is a different problem.

Any ideas to solve or circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`KeyPressEvent#getUnicodeCharCode`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyPressEvent.html#getUnicodeCharCode%28%29)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that but I'm afraid it doesn't work either. If I press "´" then "a" what I'll get is 'a' for "event.getCharCode()" or 97 for event.getUnicodeCharCode(), which is unicode for 'a'.

Comment: That's two key presses, not one. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Right, sorry for my ignorance. It seems I should be using a Java key typed event instead, only, as far as I can see, that's not implemented by gwt to use in the client package. I'm developing a simple "ghost game" supporting several languages. I need to capture the character typed by the user and process the word to find the next letter.